# Progress bar shows "echo is OFF" message

Tags: batch-file, echo

I'm trying to simulate a progress bar with ASCII characters, but any time my progress bar is more than 0% full, the message `echo is OFF` is displayed.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
color A
echo hacking main intelligence systems...
ping -n 2 127.0.0.1>nul
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo    Loading...        Please Wait
echo ---------------------------------------
echo                                    :0 ]
echo ---------------------------------------
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo    Loading.          Please Wait
echo ---------------------------------------
echo ||                                 :5 ]
echo ---------------------------------------
ping localhost -n 3 >nul
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo    Loading..         Please Wait
echo ---------------------------------------
echo ||||                              :15 ]
echo ---------------------------------------
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
```

The script continues on like that for a while, but this snippet is smaller and has the same issue.

What is causing the message to appear, and how can I correctly display the bar progressing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We really, really, _really_ don't like prank scripts. Honestly, if you had made up something about how you're making a video game (or better yet, left out the backstory altogether because _it doesn't matter_), you probably wouldn't have so many downvotes. Your actual question of "why am I getting an 'echo off' error is perfectly fine. Lose the backstory, and edit your question to actually include the code (we also really hate external links to code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your actual question of why your `echo`s aren't working is perfectly reasonable, and it's an extremely common error for beginners.

`|` is a symbol that takes the output of one command and uses it as the input of another command. In your case, you effectively have `echo` by itself, which will simply return the status of `echo` (in this case, echo is OFF).

In order to get around this, you can either use a different symbol, or you can open your code in a text editor and replace all instances of `|` with `^|`.

`^` is an escape character, which tells `echo` to interpret the symbol literally and print an actual `|` instead of using it to route command output.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
color A
echo hacking main intelligence systems...
ping -n 2 127.0.0.1>nul
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo    Loading...        Please Wait
echo ---------------------------------------
echo                                    :0 ]
echo ---------------------------------------
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo    Loading.          Please Wait
echo ---------------------------------------
echo ^|^|                                 :5 ]
echo ---------------------------------------
ping localhost -n 3 >nul
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo    Loading..         Please Wait
echo ---------------------------------------
echo ^|^|^|^|                              :15 ]
echo ---------------------------------------
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
```

Comment: Okay!Thanks it works, and by the way it's not a prank.

Comment: @ElidjayRoss - Glad to help. If my solution worked for you, please click the check mark next to my answer.